# Best way to stream PDF Files

Tags: pdf, apache-kafka, apache-storm

What would be a good way to stream PDF files through a messaging queue?

Would it be a good idea to do this in KAFKA?

Here is what i have in mind:

1. Pick up the PDF files from a file drop location.
2. Stream the files through Kafka.
3. Parse the files for some low level Info Retrieval and cleanup. This will probably be done in a Storm topology or Spark. Maybe some custom Map Reduce code.
4. Finally, i wan to run some machine learning algorithms on these documents.

Note that the steps mentioned above are just possibilities. If you have a better implementation, please suggest.

Comment: Your question is rather broad... You should give more details. How many files do you want to process per minute? Why do you need Kafka in between? Storm could access the filed directly. What kind of machine learning do you want to apply? How is this related to stream processing? Are you planning to use an library like Mahout or SAMOA?

Comment: Kafka-Storm is just part of the stack that i have to work with so i would prefer to use Kafka. I'm pretty sure i wont be processing too many files per minute as of now but hings can change in the future. You make a good point about Storm being able to pick up the files on its own. For example via a custom Spout, correct? I am trying to build a RandomForest classifier to tag and index some reports. Would you recommend Mahout? Basically, right now i have a few pieces of the Machine Learning code in Python, but i think i can replicate that in Java if needed.

Comment: I am not a machine learning guy; thus, I cannot recommend any library. Mahout is available for Spark (and soon Flink), while SAMOA is available for Storm (and soon Flink). SAMOA is tailored to streaming machine learning. (Btw: I need to and a disclaimer; I am a committer at Flink). I am just wondering if you need to have a big data system if you don't have much data. What is the data rate you expect in the future? Do you really need to be able to scale-out? About using Kafka: if there is no reason for using it, I would avoid it -- it make the overall project simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I'd break that into three problems:

1. Ingestion
2. Parsing
3. Analytics

So that you can do ingestion once but iterate on the parsing and analytics as your understanding of both the data and the problem evolve.

For ingestion, I'd push the actual file to a widely accessible location, such as HDFS or an HTTP server and then send a short message via Kafka that a file at a given location has just been added and is ready for parsing. Once the file has been parsed, store that info in a database so that you can iterate again over the entire set of ingested files if your parsing algorithm changes.

Comment: thanks for the info! i beleive i would need something like Flume/Storm/Gobblin to connect Kafka to HDFS. any thoughts on the 'best' approach?

Comment: To be clear, the producer of the Kafka message, probably a stand-alone app would be the one writing the files to, say, HDFS.  The consumer of the Kafka messages would be the one reading the files from HDFS.  In neither case is Kafka actually directly interacting with HDFS.  The consumer doesn't have to be Storm, but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: correct, all we are doing is putting the messages in Kafka and HDFS in  parallel.